# After deploying my MERN app to heroku, it tells me "server responded with a status of 503"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

the deployed app can't post or get data from my server, the client side works fine but it doesn't display data stored in my server and also can't post data to it.

this is my server index.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

    app.use(express.static("client/build"));

    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server Listening on ${port}`)
});
```

and this is my package.json scripts

```
 "scripts": {
     "client install": "npm install --prefix client",
     "start": "node server/index.js",
     "backend": "nodemon server/index.js",
     "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
     "frontend": "npm run start --prefix client",
     "dev": "concurrently \"npm run backend\" \"npm run start --prefix client\""
 },
```